# Find who executed a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there a way/any functions/DMV's in SQL Server that will provide who executed a stored procedure of a particular database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out who ran a query using transaction log backups](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82628/find-out-who-ran-a-query-using-transaction-log-backups)

Comment: He is talking about stored procedures. If procedure is selective type how will you know who executed that from log?... My question to OP, are you looking for historical requests, or you are trying to build a solution for further requests? And please update version of SQL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the stored procedure already ran and you're looking for the smoking gun, and you're looking for history without setting something up ahead of time, you'll need to [analyze the transaction log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82628/find-out-who-ran-a-query-using-transaction-log-backups).

If you're asking because you're ready to change the server or the database to be prepared the next time it happens, you can:

- Add a line to the stored procedure to log that information to a table
- Run a trace with Profiler or Extended Events, focusing just on that stored procedure
- Implement [auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)
- If the stored procedure runs for a long time, you could [log sp_WhoIsActive to a table](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/07/logging-activity-using-sp_whoisactive-take-2/) every few minutes via an Agent job, and then later go back through those logs to see who was running it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, added a liner to get the user information and logged the result in a table

Answer (score 5):

A non-technical answer:

Ask your team.

If someone was able to run a stored procedure that wrecked your database, the fault does not rest with the person that ran the sp. If you're the DBA, it's your job to make sure that the sp's are safe to run, to make them safe if they aren't and restrict access if they can't be made safe.

If you're putting energy into finding the scapegoat, think about putting energy into mending the fence, instead. Database Administration is pretty easy 95% of the time. You're getting paid to be responsible for it.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that the person asking the question is a database administrator, though. For example, they might be a developer doing a post-mortem to find out why a stored proc is still getting called even though it's been deprecated.